# Cant remove space between Header and Menu Nav bar

Tags: css, header, margin, padding, nav

I for whatever reason cannot get rid of the gap between my header and the nav bar menu.   I've tried every adjustment of padding/margins I can think of to either push it up or move the bar, but it just does funky stuff with the menu or pushes other content up.  I need some help.

and the code

```
#header_wrap {
    width:100%;
    height:144px;
    text-align: center;

}

#header {
    width:980px;
    margin:0 auto;


}

#preloadedImages
{
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    display: none;
    background-image:url(Logo/logo14hover.gif);


}

.site_logo {
    float:left;
    width:302px;
    height:144px;
    background:url(Logo/logo14.gif) no-repeat;

}

.site_logo:hover {  
    float:left;
    width:302px;
    height:144px;
    background:url(Logo/logo14hover.gif) no-repeat;

}


.headerpic { 
    float:left;
    width:678px;
    height:144px;
    background:url(Images/headerpic.gif) no-repeat;

}




#menu_wrap {
     position:relative;
         z-index:2;
    text-align:center; 
    width:100%;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    }



#menu {
     position:relative;
     z-index:2;
    width:1000px;
    text-align:center; 
    margin:0 auto;
    height:61px;
    padding: 0px 0px;
    }

nav ul ul {
    display: none;

}

    nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
    }

nav ul {

    background: #bbb38f; /* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #bbb38f 0%, #6b6441 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#bbb38f), color-stop(100%,#6b6441)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #bbb38f 0%,#6b6441 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #bbb38f 0%,#6b6441 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #bbb38f 0%,#6b6441 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #bbb38f 0%,#6b6441 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#bbb38f', endColorstr='#6b6441',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

    padding: 0px 0px;
    list-style:none;
    position: relative;
    display:inline-table;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Copperplate Gothic Light,Georgia, Palatino, Times New Roman, serif; 
    font-size:17px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-weight:light;
    outline:none;   
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #000000;

}

    nav ul:after {
        content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
    }


nav ul li {
    float: left;
}

nav ul li:hover {
        background: #736e57;
        background: linear-gradient(top, #BBB38F 0%, #6B6441 40%);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #BBB38F4 0%, #6B64415 40%);
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #BBB38F 0%,#6B6441 40%);
        text-decoration:none; 
        font-family:Copperplate Gothic Light,Georgia, Palatino, Times New Roman, serif; 
        font-size:17px;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        font-weight:light;
        outline:none;
        filter:alpha(opacity=100);
        opacity: 1;
        -moz-opacity:1;

}

nav ul li:hover a {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-opacity:1;

}

nav ul li a {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    padding: 12px 42px;
    text-decoration:none;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-opacity:1;

}



nav ul li:hover > ul {
    background: #303030;
    text-decoration:none;
    display: block;

    }

nav ul ul {
    background: #303030;

    font-family:  Helvetica, Copperplate Gothic Light, Arial, sans-serif;   
    font-size:14px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#000;
    font-weight:light;
    outline:none;
    filter:alpha(opacity=95);
    opacity: 0.95;
    -moz-opacity:0.95;
}

    nav ul ul li {
        text-decoration:none;
        float: none; 
        position: relative;

    }
        nav ul ul li a {
            text-decoration:none;
            padding: 0px 0px;
            color:#000;
            filter:alpha(opacity=100);
            opacity: 1;
            -moz-opacity:1;

        }   
            nav ul ul li a:hover {
                text-decoration:none;
                background: #736e57;
                text-shadow: 1px 1px #000000;
                filter:alpha(opacity=100);
                opacity: 1;
                -moz-opacity:1;
            }

nav ul ul {

    text-decoration:none;
    padding: 0px;
    position: absolute;



    }

    nav ul ul li {

        float: none; 
        position: relative;
    }
        nav ul ul li a {
            filter:alpha(opacity=100);
            opacity: 1;
            -moz-opacity:1;
            padding: 10px 40px 10px 15px;
            color:#000;
            font-family:  Helvetica, Copperplate Gothic Light, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size:15px;
            text-align: left;


        }   
            nav ul ul li a:hover {
                font-family:  Helvetica, Copperplate Gothic Light, Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size:15px;
                background: #6B6441;
                text-align: left;
                background: #bbb38f; /* Old browsers */
/* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #bbb38f 0%, #6b6441 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#bbb38f), color-stop(100%,#6b6441)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #bbb38f 0%,#6b6441 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #bbb38f 0%,#6b6441 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #bbb38f 0%,#6b6441 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #bbb38f 0%,#6b6441 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#bbb38f', endColorstr='#6b6441',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-opacity:1;
            }

nav ul ul ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%; top:0;

}
```

and the HTML

```
<div align="center" id="header_wrap">
<div id="header">
<a href="index.html"><div id="preloadedImages"></div><div class="site_logo"></div></a>
<div class="headerpic"></div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- START MENU NAV BAR CODE -->
<div id="menu_wrap">
<div id="menu">
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="Company/company.html">Company</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="Company/mission.html">Mission</a></li>
        <li><a href="Company/philosophy.html">Philosophy</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="Solutions/solutions.html">Solutions</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="Solutions/QPipe-Estimator/qpipe-estimator.html">Q Pipe Estimator</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="Solutions/QPipe-Estimator/advantage.html">Advantage</a></li>
            <li><a href="Solutions/QPipe-Estimator/differentiator.html">Differentiator</a></li>
            <li><a href="Solutions/QPipe-Estimator/features.html">Features</a></li>
            <li><a href="Solutions/QPipe-Estimator/screenshots.html">Screen Shots</a></li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
        </li>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="Services/technical-support.html">Technical Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="Services/training.html">Training</a></li>
        <li><a href="Services/customization.html">Customization</a></li>
        <li><a href="Services/faqs.html">FAQ's</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Industry</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="Industry/focus.html">Focus</a></li>
        <li><a href="Industry/customers.html">Customers</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="Contact/contact-information.html">Contact</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="Contact/contact-information.html">Contact Information</a></li>
        <li><a href="Contact/request-information.html">Request Information</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="http://web.qsoftsolutions.com/">Login</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
<!-- END MENU NAV BAR CODE -->
```

added fiddle link in comments

Comment: That's your CSS, where's HTML? Setting up fiddle would increase your chances of getting an answer and speed it up

Comment: please provide the html markup and/or an example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) too.

Comment: Could you post a html version to match you problem, so we can test it out.

Comment: UL have a default margin? I see this problem a lot where the margin on an element when it's parent is floating creates a space difficult to find.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gramw/xtsAx/5

Comment: @GrahamWietzke You can easily discover such problems by using the webdeveloper tools avaiable in all browsers. Just press F12 or right click on an element and "inspect" it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simply remove the default margin for your main `ul` (the direct descendant of `nav`)

Select it using the following CSS, or giving that specific `ul` a `class` or `id` (this way you target only the `ul` causing you trouble).

```
nav > ul {margin: 0}
```

I stuck it into the top of your fiddle, and updated it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xtsAx/9/)

I realise this has now been answered because I took way too long formatting this, but I'd just like to point out that it has nothing to do with the `box-shadow` which has no impact on positioning.

Answer (score 2):

The `ul` default margin is responsible for this space. Try setting `margin-top:0` to `nav ul`. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xtsAx/8/

Comment: Awesome work!  Thanks, I had to readjust all the content that goes below the navbar with some negative margins but works great.  Thank you so much.

Comment: If you're OK with the answer, please accept it and tick it as "answered".

Comment: Having an issue with my dropdowns now,  when I mouseover to scroll through them it doesnt work right on the hover, Im assuming cause i've shifted the menu up.

Comment: How do you get this issue? What browser are you using?

Comment: Firefox same with IE9, Ive set margin-top:2px;

Comment: John is right below. The space is occupied by the `ul` default margin and not the shadow. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

for me the error was because i used dream weaver to edit my code.
this give me a hiccup by **adding default headers**.
when i removed those headers and just gave`<html> <head>...<?php>....?> .... </html>` it worked perfect.
**always remove html tags and header by dream weaver.**

**Update: I had the same error again in Firefox so i applied

```
    *{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

And hence got rid of it completely now.
**